# Movement of Common Jelly Fish

Tags: zoology, limnology, movement

Among the different types of movements in the bodies of various organisms, the movement exhibited by jelly fishes are very unique and peculiar in some ways. I can't understand how to classify the type of movement for jelly fish.

Its movement is also similar to octopuses and squids, but they have proper propelling arms which they use to propel themselves forward. Whereas Jelly Fishes don't have such structres in them, then how are they producing such movements?

Also they outer structure (often known as "bell" or "hood") is made up of an external epidermis and an internal gastrodermis (containing nerves but no muscles) and their bodies are mostly water, so how are they able to produce such movements.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Questions without evidence of a search in an attempt to answer are off-topic. (E.g. did you google "how to jellyfish swim"?) Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I obviously did the research and I have noted my inferences in the description of my question. I also mentioned what I don't understand particularly and so I asked them as I didn't get any satisfied on Google. If there was a way to just get all the answers from the web then I wouldn't use this site. If I google how jelly fish swims? do you really think that will aswer my question, Put some thought into it. I didn't ask this doubt particularly here for no reason, if I just could have got my answers on Google.

Comment: Also it is a not a question about species identification or something, I don't know what kind of "evidence" I have to submit to ask a question on concept.

Comment: It's not obvious that you researched it because we see no sources. You must wonder what kind of Q&A site this is, being asked to show your search results; shouldn't we just answer your question? Actually, no. We're expected to help if we so choose. We're scientists or people interested in science, a lot of us teach, practice, or research some aspect of Biology. We expect some meaningful degree of research (show a source + a quote); not a ton, but not nothing, either. Consider this kind of like a classroom, not a chat room. You'll get a (better) response with a better effort on your part.

Comment: Also, I googled "how do jellyfish swim" just to see what was out there, and my first hit answered the question. Usually with multicellular organisms like jellyfish, movement involves muscle tissue. There are lots of ways to move in the ocean, but clearly jellyfish propel themselves, so... muscle.